# JavaScript - scrollIntoView() with no animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using .scrollIntoView(true) to scroll to an element and put it at the top of the page on the screen. I love the behavior of this but I'd rather there be no scroll animation and that it would just jump to the element and put it at the top of the page instead.

Is there a way to do .jumpIntoView() or something like that with JavaScript or Jquery?

I want it to put the element at the top of the page and jump to it, no scroll animation.

```
<div id='breakOne'>Break 1</div>

<script>

document.getElementByID('breakOne').scrollIntoView(true);

</script>
```

Comment: The linked question is totally unrelated. You need to use `scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant"})`

Comment: Thanks Christian, this is exactly what I needed! I know, people who close questions are really annoying. I appreciate your comment